# How to display 3 buttons on the same line in css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I want to display 3 buttons on the same line in html. I tried two options: 
This one:

```
    <div style="width:500px;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 130px"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button></div>
        <div style ="float: none; width: 130px"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button></div>
        <div style ="float: right; width: 130px"><button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button></div>
    </div>
```

And this one:

```
    <p style="float: left; width: 130px"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button></p>
    <p style ="float: none; width: 130px"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button></p>
    <p style ="float: right; width: 130px"><button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button></p>
```

For the second option I used a styling for the paragraph:

```
<style>
   p {display:inline}
</style>
```

Sadly, none of them were ok, and I can't seem to find out any other option. The first and second button are displayed on same line, but the third is displayed lower...
Can you help me?

Comment: float them all left, and make sure that the width of the div or container they are in is wider than the total width of all the buttons

Comment: Is there a reason you put the buttons in a `div` or a `p` tag?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LEn9R/ Just float all of them left. `p` tag stands for paragraph, and it seems pretty obvious that 2 paragraphs shouldn't be on the same line, so avoid using `p` for this.

Comment: @putvande not really, I thought I would need that but it isn't useful right now...

Comment: Just remove all the `p` tag and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Note that I am just learning about CSS. This question may have been very easy, so I am sorry about that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is the Answer

CSS

```
#outer
{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
  <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button></div>
  <div class="inner"><button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button></div>
  <div class="inner"><button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button></div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6uL5e/)

Comment: +1 : but assigning the `inline-block` `class` to buttons would be a better idea rather than wrapping them in class :)

Comment: 3years later is still a really great answer ! Thank you for that

Answer (score 4):

Do something like this,

**HTML :**

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button>
    <button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
div button{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7cBvj/2/)

Or

**HTML :**

```
<div style="width:500px;" id="container">
    <div><button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button></div>
    <div><button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button></div>
    <div><button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
#container div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:130px;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/7cBvj/3/)

Comment: incorrect `display:inline;` will remove the possibility to style the button for height and width!!

Answer (score 3):

This will serve the purpose. There is no need for any divs or paragraph. If you want the spaces between them to be specified, use margin-left or margin-right in the css classes.

```
<div style="width:500px;">
    <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button>
    <button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to float all the buttons to left and make sure its width to fit within outer container.

**CSS:**

```
.btn{

   float:left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" onClick="return false;">Publish</button>
    <button class="btn">Back</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap then call a simple **btn-group** class in the outer div

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="">View</a>
  <a href="">Edit</a>
  <a href="">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will display all 3 buttons on the same line provided there is enough horizontal space to display them:

```
<button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;" >Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">Publish</button>
<button class="msgBtnBack">Back</button>
// Note the lack of unnecessary divs, floats, etc.
```

The only reason the buttons wouldn't display inline is if they have had display:block applied to them within your css.