# How to make two buttons on the same row?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I create two buttons then I atach them to the same do=iv with id=dvSearchTitle.

Here is the code:

```
     var button = $('<button/>', {
             text: data.d.txtSearch, 
             id: 'btnFeatureLocation',
             click: function () 
             {  
                        parent.parent.mapFrame.SetSelectionXML(data.d.featureSelection);
                        parent.parent.mapFrame.ZoomSelection();     
             }
        }); 

             var button2 = $('<button/>', {
             text: "ddd", 
             id: 'ddd',
             click: function () 
             {  
                alert("ddd");
             }
        }); 

    $('#dvSearchTitle').append(button);
    $('#dvSearchTitle').append(button2);
```

The result I get two button one above another.

I need to make two buttons on the same row.

**UPDATE**

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3z39gewb/1/).

What do I need to change to make two buttons on the same row?

Comment: Please provide working code or link.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. There must be some problem with your css. Please post your CSS too.

Comment: @ankitapatel please see update

Comment: You just need to remove the `width: 100%` you have declared on `#btnFeatureLocation`, see: https://jsfiddle.net/3z39gewb/2/

Answer (score 1):

try this in your css:

```
#dvSearchTitle button {display:inline-block}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376901/3412965)

in short:

```
style ="display: inline-block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change width btnFeatureLocation 100% to 50% and add same css in second button.

```js
   var button = $('<button/>', {
     text: "button1", 
     id: 'btnFeatureLocation',
     click: function () 
     {  
       //some logic
     }
   }); 
   
   var button2 = $('<button/>', {
     text: "button2", 
     id: 'ddd',
     click: function () 
     {  
     alert("ddd");
     }
   }); 
   
      
  $('#dvSearchTitle').append(button);
  $('#dvSearchTitle').append(button2);
```

```css
.exosphere{
 border: solid 1px #333;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
}


.searchResults{
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255,0.7);
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:100;
 left: 20%;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: Arial; 
 font-size: 14pt;
}


#btnFeatureLocation{
  width: 50%; 
  height:40px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font-weight: bold; 
}

#ddd{
  width: 50%; 
  height:40px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvSearchTitle" class="exosphere searchResults"></div>
```