# Display buttons side by side instead of stacked

Tags: html, css

I want to display the buttons inside my modalpopupextender side by side instead of stacked on top of each other. Below is the image:

[image]

I want the remove and cancel button side by side. Below is my code:

```
     <div >
                                    <p style="width:200px;height:100px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto">
                                        <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server"  Text="Remove"  CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CartID") %>'/>
                                        <asp:Button ID="CancelButton"  runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                                    </p>
   </div>
```

Comment: use  display: inline-block;

Comment: I tried it, still the same thing. Below is the code:    <p style="width:200px;height:100px;display: inline-block;">

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376901/3143426 this answer should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use display flex for it

```
p {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p Button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Check it out
https://jsfiddle.net/L95j0kd7/1/

Comment: worked right away, but there is no space between the buttons. Should I put &nbsp; between the button.

Comment: @Anjali, don't use `&nbsp;`. Create a rule of `justify-content: space-between;` and a `width: 220px;` for `p` tag, that creates any space.